# Proving that $π^e$ is irrational

Tags: exponential-function, pi

I tried for a few hours to come with a proof that $π^e$ is irrational. I mainly tried with the method "proof by contradiction" and didn't use calculus at all, but couldn't come up with a proof.

Can anyone give a proof that $π^e$ is irrational? I would appreaciate if it was without using calculus. because that's more fun, but it's completly fine  using calculus too :) Just want to see a proof.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is unknown

Comment: @Peter What? Seriously? Without calculus even? Ooo that's a fun challenge for a 14 year old math lover :DD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves speculation about an open problem in mathematics.  I don't think that such speculation is on-topic here (though I suspect that a question about what is known about the ir/rationality of $\pi^\mathrm{e}$ might be both (1) on-topic and (2) already answered here somewhere).

Comment: Good hazing for a young mathematician!

Comment: Link to a list of combinations of $\pi$ and $\mathrm{e}$ which are not know to be transcendental (but might be):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possibly_transcendental_numbers

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767240/is-large-pie-rational, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952889/pi-and-e-problem

Comment: @EricTowers ty for that page

Comment: Note that $e^\pi$ _is_ proven to be transcendental on the same wiki page. However, the proof is only easy if we can use the Gelfond-Schneider theorem and apply it to $(-1)^{-i}$.